# Need to validate nested json arrays in play 2.1 in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I was able to perform simple validations on simple json structures like this one:

```
object RestTest extends Controller {

  case class Address(street: String,
                     number: Int)

  case class Person(name: String,
                    age: Int,
                    address: Address)

  implicit  val address = Json.reads[Address]
  implicit val rds = Json.reads[Person]

  def restTest = Action(parse.json) {
    request =>

      request.body.validate[Person].map {
          case person => Ok(Json.obj("e" -> 0, "message" -> ("The name is: " + person.name + " and he lives in " + person.address.street)))
        }.recoverTotal(e => Ok("e" -> 1)
      }
}
```

Now I have the following structure that contains arrays, but I wasn't able to validate it correctly so far. I have tried many different ways, but I keep receiving compilation errors.

```
case class SecondStructure(index: Int)

case class EntryStructure(field1: String,
                  muSecondJsonArray: List[SecondStructure])

case class MyJsonArray(allEntries: List[EntryStructure])
```

How can I validate this json?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, ensure you are using the latest Play 2.1.1 releases. There was an issue with earlier versions when validating case classes with a single field. After that, it should all work - please see below for an example:

```
object JsonTest {
  case class SecondStructure(index: Int)

  case class EntryStructure(field1: String, muSecondJsonArray: List[SecondStructure])

  case class MyJsonArray(allEntries: List[EntryStructure])

  // Use the macro "inception" feature to automatically build your Readers.
  implicit val ssReads = Json.reads[SecondStructure]
  implicit val esReads = Json.reads[EntryStructure]
  implicit val arrayReads = Json.reads[MyJsonArray]

  // Defining an example instance...
  val testArray = MyJsonArray(
    List(
      EntryStructure("foo", List(SecondStructure(1), SecondStructure(2))),
      EntryStructure("bar", List(SecondStructure(3), SecondStructure(4)))))

  // And the equivilant JSON structure...
  val testJson = Json.obj("allEntries" ->
    Json.arr(
      Json.obj("field1" -> "foo", "muSecondJsonArray" -> Json.arr(
        Json.obj("index" -> 1), Json.obj("index" -> 2))),
      Json.obj("field1" -> "bar", "muSecondJsonArray" -> Json.arr(
        Json.obj("index" -> 3), Json.obj("index" -> 4)))))

  testJson.validate[MyJsonArray].map {
    case foo if foo == testArray => println("Okay, we're good!")
  }
}
```